# How to iterate array of strings in Rust 0.7

Tags: arrays, loops, vector, rust

How do I iterate through array of strings in Rust 0.7?

My array (or vector?) of strings is returned by **sock.read_lines();** and I would like to print the contents of the array line by line. I dont quite understand how to do it since Rust documentation is incomplete and too sparse at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `sock.read_lines()` returns something of type `~[~str]` then you can iterate through this vector with the following code:

```
for sock.read_lines().iter().advance |line| {
    // Do somthing with line
}
```

This is described in [containers and iterators tutorial](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.7/tutorial-container.html) which is accessible from the main tutorial, see links at the bottom.

Comment: After Rust 0.7, this becomes `for line in sock.read_lines().iter() {`.